# Angular Js curly braces in rails erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, erb

Does anyone know if it is possible to render angular js curly braces type {{ }}
in ERB as parameters.

eg.

```
 <=home_url( {{code.id}}, @code)/>
```

Comment: Think about when `home_url(...)` is evaluated by rails (hint: before the page ever gets to the client).  Think about when `{{code.id}}` would be evaluated by angularjs.

Comment: still not getting it? im a bit of a nube when it comes to rails

Comment: `home_url(...)` is ruby code that is run on the server and spits out your HTML document.  `{{code.id}}` is executed by angularjs (javascript) on your user's computer after it gets the HTML page (rendered by ruby!) from your server.  Does that make sense?

Comment: yes so that mean its not possible. thanks

Comment: do know of a solution to get that code.id in the link, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated thanks

Comment: im using ng-repeat to iterate over some json objects and trying to add {{code.id}} as a parmeter for a rails route. any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the example from [here](http://coderberry.me/blog/2013/04/23/angularjs-on-rails-4-part-2/):

```
<div>
  <label>Name:</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">
  <hr>
  <h1>Hello {{yourName}}!</h1>
</div>
```

Also check this tutorial: http://blog.berylliumwork.com/2013/03/best-practice-of-using-angularjs-with.html

where you can see this example:

```
<div data-ng-init='mailbox.selected = "<%= @current_page %>"'>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li data-ng-class='{active: (mailbox.selected == "inbox")}'>
    <%= link_to mails_inbox_path, 'Inbox' %>
  </li>
  <li data-ng-class='{active: (mailbox.selected == "outbox")}'>
    <%= link_to mails_outbox_path, 'Outbox' %>
  </li>
  <li data-ng-class='{active: (mailbox.selected == "draft")}'>
    <%= link_to mails_draft_path, 'Draft' %>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```